# How to update what image you open with image.open()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm just curious how I would go about updating the image opened with the Zoom function WITHOUT calling the Zoom function again. Also if you know of any easier way to do what I'm doing, which is simply just trying to make a image "Zoom-able" with mouse wheel, then my ears are open lol. Any other comments on the code are appreciated, Thank You!

Specifically this part right here:

```
pictureVar = StringVar()
pictureVar.set("a.png")

Zoom(root, path=pictureVar.get())

pictureVar.set("b.png")
```

The picture then gets opened using Image.open() here:

```
class Zoom(Frame):
    ''' Simple zoom with mouse wheel '''
    def __init__(self, mainframe, path):
        ''' Initialize the main Frame '''
        Frame.__init__(self, master=mainframe)
        # Vertical and horizontal scrollbars for canvas
        vbar = AutoScrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical')
        hbar = AutoScrollbar(self.master, orient='horizontal')
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        # Open image
        self.image = Image.open(path)  #<------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Here is the entire code though:

```
import csv
import os
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    ''' A scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.
        Works only if you use the grid geometry manager '''
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            self.grid_remove()
        else:
            self.grid()
        Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)


class Zoom(Frame):
    ''' Simple zoom with mouse wheel '''
    def __init__(self, mainframe, path):
        ''' Initialize the main Frame '''
        Frame.__init__(self, master=mainframe)
        # Vertical and horizontal scrollbars for canvas
        vbar = AutoScrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical')
        hbar = AutoScrollbar(self.master, orient='horizontal')
        vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        # Open image
        self.image = Image.open(path)
        # Create canvas and put image on it
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, highlightthickness=0,
                                xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        vbar.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)  # bind scrollbars to the canvas
        hbar.configure(command=self.canvas.xview)
        # Make the canvas expandable
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Bind events to the Canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.move_from)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>',     self.move_to)
        self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.wheel)
        self.imscale = 0.25
        self.imageid = None
        self.delta = 0.75
        # Text is used to set proper coordinates to the image. You can make it invisible.
        self.text = self.canvas.create_text(0, 0, anchor='nw', text='')
        self.show_image()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def move_from(self, event):
        ''' Remember previous coordinates for scrolling with the mouse '''
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def move_to(self, event):
        ''' Drag (move) canvas to the new position '''
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    def wheel(self, event):
        ''' Zoom with mouse wheel '''
        scale = 1.0
        # Respond to Linux (event.num) or Windows (event.delta) wheel event
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            scale        *= self.delta
            self.imscale *= self.delta
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == 120:
            scale        /= self.delta
            self.imscale /= self.delta
        # Rescale all canvas objects
        x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
        self.canvas.scale('all', x, y, scale, scale)
        self.show_image()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def show_image(self):
        ''' Show image on the Canvas '''
        if self.imageid:
            self.canvas.delete(self.imageid)
            self.imageid = None
            self.canvas.imagetk = None  # delete previous image from the canvas
        width, height = self.image.size
        new_size = int(self.imscale * width), int(self.imscale * height)
        imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.resize(new_size))
        # Use self.text object to set proper coordinates
        self.imageid = self.canvas.create_image(self.canvas.coords(self.text),
                                                anchor='nw', image=imagetk)
        self.canvas.lower(self.imageid)  # set it into background
        self.canvas.imagetk = imagetk  # keep an extra reference to prevent garbage-collection


pictureVar = StringVar()
pictureVar.set("a.png")

Zoom(root, path=pictureVar.get())

pictureVar.set("b.png")

mainloop()
```

Comment: [mcve] please. You don't even mention what part of your code dump is relevant...

Comment: @Julien I'm sorry... I'm newish I don't come on here often and am not super experienced at coding. I updated it if that helps.

Comment: So what is preventing you from creating an `update_image(self, path)` method that does just that?

Comment: `Zoom` isn't a function, it's a `class`. When you call a class it creates an instance and initializes it by calling the class' `__init__()` method. The instance value will become the first argument, conventionally called `self`, that will automatically be passed to all the other methods of the defined `class`. If the `Image` is attached to a `Canvas`, then you can use the `imageid` to update the `Canvas` later if necessary.